# Why the cube keeps shaking in ursina?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ursina

I'm trying to use ursina to make a game but there are some problems while running my code

I want my cube to move while I press `arrows` and camera moves with `wasd`

It works well but the cube keeps shaking while moving

When I press `UP arrow`, it moves with shaking

But it doesn't when I stop pressing `arrows`

It just can not move fluently

Is there any way that can solve this problem?

There must be something wrong with my code

Here is my code:

```
import ursina as us

app = us.Ursina()


class Player(us.Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            parent=us.scene,
            model='cube',
            position=(0, 1, 0),
            rotation=(0, 45, 0),
            texture='white_cube',
            color=us.color.azure,
            )
        us.camera.position = (0, 2, 5)
        us.camera.look_at(self)
        
        self.speed = 5
        self.gravity = 0.01
        self.strength = 0.2
        self.v = None
        
    def update(self):
        us.camera.look_at(self)
        
        if us.held_keys['up arrow']:
            self.position += self.forward * us.time.dt * self.speed
        if us.held_keys['down arrow']:
            self.position += self.back * us.time.dt * self.speed
        if us.held_keys['right arrow']:
            self.rotation += (0, 5, 0)
        if us.held_keys['left arrow']:
            self.rotation += (0, -5, 0)
        
        if us.held_keys['w']:
            us.camera.position += us.camera.forward * us.time.dt
        if us.held_keys['s']:
            us.camera.position += us.camera.back * us.time.dt
        if us.held_keys['d']:
            us.camera.position += us.camera.right * us.time.dt
        if us.held_keys['a']:
            us.camera.position += us.camera.left * us.time.dt
        
        if us.held_keys['left shift']:
            player.speed = 10
        else:
            player.speed = 5
        
        if us.held_keys['space']:
            self.jump()
        
        
        if self.v != None:
            self.v -= self.gravity
            if self.v > -self.strength:
                self.position += (0, self.v, 0)
            else:
                self.v = None
        
        
    def jump(self):
        if self.v == None:
            self.v = self.strength

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    player = Player()
    us.Sky()
    
    
    app.run()
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Move `camera.look_at(self)` to the bottom of the update function, so it does the look_at after you've moved the camera.